# Почему все переменные в интерфейсе являются final?

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, интерфейс

И всетаки, почему все переменные в интерфейсе являются final? Для чего это ключевое слово тут? В чем его смысл?

Для чего вообще это ключевое слово там?

Пусть бы они были не final!

Что тогда?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Интерфейс определяет поведение объектов, а не конкретную реализацию. Если бы мы могли переопределять значения в дочерних интерфейсах или классах, реализующих этот интерфейс, то часть нашего интерфейса становилась бы частью конкретной реализации, что нарушало бы исходное понятие термина "интерфейс".

Поскольку создавать экземпляры интерфейса нельзя и интерфейс не должен быть связан с конкретной реализацией, то неявно используется ключевое слово `static` (то есть данное поле определено в контексте, где нет никаких объектов). Отсутствие модификатора `final` также приводило бы к неоднозначности и путанице, поскольку каждый класс/интерфейс мог бы по своему усмотрению изменять это значение, что влияло бы на другие классы/интерфейсы. Но тут стоит заметить, что неизменяемость характерна для примитивных типов данных и `immutable` классов, для остальных же классов - `final` гарантирует только неизменяемость ссылки на область памяти, в которой расположен объект. Поля самого объекта при этом могут быть изменяемы.

Если предположить возможность, что интерфейс может иметь нестатические изменяемые поля, то тогда бы возникла проблема с ромбовидным наследованием (diamond inheritance). Допустим, есть интерфейс **A**, в котором определено поле `int v = 10`. От этого интерфейса наследуются два других интерфейса **B** и **C**, каждый из которых переопределяет нашу переменную `v` (например, в **B** имеем значение 15, а в **C** - 20). Теперь мы определяем еще один интерфейс **D**, который наследуется от **B** и **C**. Тогда возникает вопрос: какое значение поле `v` должно унаследовать?

Comment: Отличный ответ! Мне кажется самый верный!

Comment: P.S. В интерфейсе все поля public static final, а статичные поля не наследуются.

Answer (score 1):

final использует для того что бы переменному давали значение только один раз.

К примеру:

1. Если классу дали final тогда нельзя из этого класса создать *подкласс*.
2. Если в классе есть методы с final. И вы создаете подклассы, Вы не сможете *Переписать (Overwrite)* этот метод. Это удобно, когда Вам не хочется что бы метод переписивали, и использовали в других целях. Примеру, функция sin(x).
3. Если переменная имеет final, тогда вы можете передать значение этому переменному только 1 раз. Далже компилятор не дасть изменять значение. Это Удобно когда нужно объявлять константы. Что бы не чайно не изменить значение Переменной-константы. К примеру, pi = 3.1415